# Knockout not working: Value from external Json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, getjson

I was trying to create a spreadsheet kind of formula manipulation using knockout but knockout is not working.

My data is from an external Json file

Json file

```
{
    "info": [
        {
            "Name":"Noob Here",
            "Major":"Language",
            "Sex":"Male",
        "English":"15",
        "Japanese":"5",
        "Calculus":"0",
        "Geometry":"20" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadData(fileName) {
        // getting json from a remote file
        // by returning the jqXHR object we can use the .done() function on it
        // so the callback gets executed as soon as the request returns successfully
        var data = $.getJSON(fileName + ".json");
        return (data);

    }

    function fillDataTable(data) {
        // iterate over each entry in the data.info array
        $.each(data.info, function(index, element) {
            // append it to the table 
            $("#div1").append("<tr><td>" + element.Name + "</td><td>" + element.Major + "</td><td>" + element.Sex + "</td><td>" + "<input data-bind='value: eng' value=" + element.English + "></td><td>" + "<input data-bind='value: jap' value=" + element.Japanese + "></td><td>" + "<input data-bind='value: cal' value=" + element.Calculus + "></td><td>" + "<input data-bind='value: geo' value=" + element.Geometry + "></td><td>" + "<strong data-bind='text: total'></td>")
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // the file's name. "Data" in this example.
        var myFile = "Data2";

        loadData(myFile).done(function(data) {
            // check if we acutally get something back and if the data has the info property
            if (data && data.info) {
                // now fill the data table with our data
                fillDataTable(data)
            }
        });

        // This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
        function AppViewModel() {
            this.eng = ko.observable("0");
            this.jap = ko.observable("0");
            this.cal = ko.observable("0");
            this.geo = ko.observable("0");

            this.total = ko.computed(function() {
                var tot = parseFloat(this.eng()) + parseFloat(this.jap()) + parseFloat(this.cal()) + parseFloat(this.geo());
                return (tot);
            }, this);

        }

        // Activates knockout.js
        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
    });
</script>
```

My HTMl

```
<table cellspacing="1" id="div1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Major</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>English</th>
            <th>Japanese</th>
            <th>Calculus</th>
            <th>Geometry</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm getting data from json file. But knockout is not working.

Fiddle with code: http://jsfiddle.net/KGKpw/

Note: I added fiddle is just to show the code neatly.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because you haven't got jQuery running, and you are trying to load data from a local file.

Comment: I added fiddle is just to show the code neatly.

Comment: Sure, but people generally use them to debug and help out.

Comment: Ya I know. But i cant use that to show working of my code. sorry

Comment: You can put the json into the fiddle, then people can use it. Otherwise we're just looking at your code and guessing what the problem might be.

Comment: What is `done` function? According `getJSON` docs it should be `success`, or Im missing something?

Comment: @PaulManzotti: How can i add json file in fiddle? my belief is that only json data can be added.

Comment: @PeterM 'done' function works when the 'loadData' function is a success

Comment: I meant put the JSON in as a string in your javascript, or, and this is probably easier, put it in as a JS object, and just pretend that you've parsed the JSON already.

Comment: Knockout is working if i alert 'tot' within the computed function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more usual to copy your data into observable properties on your view model, and then bind those to your html elements. You are creating the html in js, rather than using doing it using knockout in the front end (using a foreach if you have multiple results to create rows for). Also whilst you have bound them, you are then setting the values directly in the html, using your data object. At a guess, the binding is enacted on *after* you have set the values in the html, and as all your observables are set to zero, that will over-write the values that you have set directly in the html.

Try moving the html into your view, rather than in your view model, copy your data from your js object to your view model, and then only use knockout binding to link the view to your view model.

Comment: Knockout is working if i alert 'tot' within the computed function.

Comment: I did it by knockout mapping

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `data-bind` in the html to bind the viewmodel to the view.

Updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KGKpw/1/

Comment: This doesn't populate his table with rows dynamically though, does it?